# how should I get the size of NSUserDefaults - swift

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I know that there is already a question just like this but that is for objective c. I need the size of my NSUserDefaults in swift.

Comment: What do you mean by "size"?  (...number of elements?  You can get a dictionary representation of the defaults and then a count of items in the dictionary.)

Comment: You could find it (depends on sandbox or not) with the file manager and get the file size from there.

Comment: how would you get a dictionary representation of the NSUserDefaults

Comment: Maybe `dictionaryRepresentation()`?  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you want to see all UserDefaults as a dict. This should do it (and log to console):

```
var allDefaultsAsDict = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation()
NSLog("All defaults: %@", allDefaultsAsDict)
```